# Passing multiple optional parameter/value pairs with user defined pair order

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-routing, codeigniter-url, remap

Say user is going to search on 4 or 5 fields, ok? eg. he might want to search by firstname, email, mobile or even page number

I want that codeigniter's url be like this:

```
site.com/Controller/Method/variable1/value1/variable2/value2/variable3/value3
```

or

```
site.com/Controller/Method/variable2/value2/variable3/value3/variable1/value1
```

(that they should have the same result)

or in this format

```
site.com/Controller/Method/variable2/value2/variable4/value4
```

some examples to clarify my question:

```
site.com/user/search/firstname/John/mobile/123/page/2
```

or:

```
site.com/user/search/lastname/Smith/email/gmail.com
```

In one sentence: I don't want to force the user to use a specific order when setting value to parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the _remap function on the controller.

```
function _remap( $method, $params )
{
    $map = array();
    for( $i = 1; $i < count( $params ); $i = $i + 2 )
    {
        $map[$params[$i-1]] = $params[$i];
    }

    if( $method[0] != '_' && method_exists( $this, $method ))
        return $this->$method( $map );
}
```

If you want to use it across all your controllers, you would be better to write a custom controller to extend CI_controller with this function, and have all your controllers extend that.

Comment: But there's still a question: why did you code the last if? It should work without that. We are giving other parameter/value pairs as an array to $method, but why should we need the final if?

Comment: In code igniter, methods that a prefixed with an underscore are private in controllers.  You're not supposed to be able to run them from the URL.  Like the _remap function.  Without it you can call _remap and others from the URL (http://yoursite.com/controller/_remap/), which would lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd pass all the parameters as 1 string with separators eg. `/username|alunr#category|99` etc. and find the values from there using [php's `explode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: I believe it'd lose its standard format when using another separator than the /

Comment: the slashes will be parsed according to the .htaccess file.  other characters shouldn't damage it.