# Code Igniter, multiple passing parameters in method

Tags: codeigniter, function, url-parameters

I have an method in Code Igniter, and want access using this URL "kuesioner/test/school_id/6/parent_id/7"
I using _remap function to dynamic order of params in URL. Code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870913/passing-multiple-optional-parameter-value-pairs-with-user-defined-pair-order).
This is my code :

```
public function test($school_id, $parent_id)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($schoold_id);
    print_r($parent_id);
    echo "</pre>";
}

public function _remap($method, $params)
{
    $map = array();
    for( $i = 1; $i < count( $params ); $i = $i + 2 )
    {
        $map[$params[$i-1]] = $params[$i];
    }

    if( $method[0] != '_' && method_exists( $this, $method ))
        return $this->$method($map);
}
```

Getting error on my controller that said Missing argument 2 for Kuesioner::test() ($parent_id is missing), it return array of map into single variable $school_id in test controller.

print_r($school_id) exactly show

```
  Array
  (
    [school_id] => 6
    [parent_id] => 7
  )
```

How to solve this, so that value can be put into every right variable..

Answer (score 1):

Always assign parameter with default values like 0 or anything else it will prevent from unnecessary warning and errors.

```
public function test($school_id = 0, $parent_id = 0)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($schoold_id);
    print_r($parent_id);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: What I want is when I request "kuesioner/test/school_id/6/parent_id/7" in test method it would print $school_id = 6 and $parent_id = 7. That's it.

Comment: I think CI automatically do this without any extra efforts. I am suggesting you to initialize these parameter will help you to prevent from warnings and errors

Comment: And when I request "kuesioner/test/parent_id/7", it should only giving value 7 to var $parent_id in test function.

Comment: But what happened now is in test method, it return only single variable for $school_id that valued
Array
  (
    [school_id] => 6
    [parent_id] => 7
  )

$parent_id always 0 right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function test($params = NULL)
{
    print_r($this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3));
    // #CHECK http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html
}
```

Comment: Yes I appreciate your solving, but I want to strict focus about my problem. Still want to know how to return value $map with right purpose to every parameter in test method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace last line with this:

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $map);
```

I think that would solve your issue,however if not, you can edit your "test" function to :

```
public function test($params)
{
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($params['schoold_id']);
  print_r($params['parent_id']);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

why you don't try with $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n). 
See detail : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html
don't need to use _remap

Comment: Did you missing code in last? I have tryyour code, but it's return blank. There is no variable that take to test method.

Comment: yes. I miss   return $this->$method($map); at last of function

Comment: why you don't try with $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(n). http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html . don't need to use _remap

Comment: Please edit this answer according to your suggestion to use $this->uir->uri_to_assoc(n). You don't want to leave the answer misleading other users.